# Cannot retrieve data from WCF because of max message size quota

Tags: wcf

I just got the task to reference a WCF Service with basicHttpbinding from a MVC client, all was working fine until the time I had to show a DropDownMenu with information of a very populated table (just the text and value of selected fields as a dropdown works) - I'm talking about of 5000 records-.
show the info in the dropdownmenu is a must in the project and so far I did manage to show the info of 50 records(so imho is not MVC dropdown problem) but when it comes to show the whole record stored in the table got this message

[image]

As I mentioned I'm using basicHttpbinding and all was working fine until got the error message, so I did some changes in the Web.config and it looks like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
             maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SIFP_GFC" connectionString="Dsn=sifp_desarrollo"
        providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

But still got the same problem, could you please tell me what do I have to do in order to show the data in the dropdownmenu properly?

Comment: The *client's* limits have to be increased as well. On the other hand, you can't display even 20 items in a dropdown without it becoming unusable, much less 5000. That will result in a *very* bad UI. That's why all applications and web sites use search combos in this case. As the user types 2 or three letters, the combo starts asking for items that start with these letters

Comment: Why are you creating a *WCF* service when you use MVC? You can return the combo data from a controller action. You can also use one of the available Jquery combos with search functionality to send what the user types to the controller method and retrieve what needs to be displayed. You can do that in an asynchronous manner as well, with an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override configuration, press right button to endpoint (in wcf test client), choose `edit config` and rewrite configuration as in a server binding